# reading two webcams in opencv

Tags: pi-3b+, python-3, opencv

If I run this code on a PC with two webcams attached it runs fast (or fast enough) without any issues:

```
import cv2

cap0 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)

while True:
    ret0, img0 = cap0.read()
    print('read 0')
    ret0, img1 = cap1.read()
    print('read 1')
```

When I run the same code on Rpi3B+, I get this output. It cannot read the second camera and even if the first camera is being read, it's so slow it's unusable:

```
read 0
[ WARN:0@11.823] global /tmp/pip-wheel-efxaz4j7/opencv-python_bedc0fac27944da0921e079da44d32bf/opencv/modules/videoio/src/cap_v4l.cpp (1000) tryIoctl VIDEOIO(V4L2:/dev/video1): select() timeout.
read 1
```

Somehow OpenCV on RPi cannot properly do `cv2.VideoCapture` on two cameras. I've tried using threads and QThreads, but that doesn't help. If you change the loop to capture and release the camera in every loop step, it works: but it's too slow (< 1 FPS):

```
import cv2

while True:
    cap0 = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    ret0, img0 = cap0.read()
    cap0.release()
    print('read 0')
    cap1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    ret1, img1 = cap1.read()
    print('read 1')
    cap1.release()
```

Are there any tricks to overcome the limitations of OpenCV on RPi?

Update: I degraded resolution from 640x480 (default) to 320x240 per [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/33031/145989) and it seems to work. However, that resolution may not be usable. I'm basically just asking for one frame at a time. It's confusing to me why  reducing resolution makes such a huge difference.

```
cap0.set(3,320)
cap0.set(4,240)
cap1.set(3,320)
cap1.set(4,240)
```

Comment: try the following ... it may point to the problem area ... keep only the `cap0` code from the first script and run it ... then create a second script for `cap1` and run it at the same time in a separate terminal window

Comment: @jsotola. Interesting thought. I tried your idea. cap0 and cap1 in separate scripts. First launch cap0 script. Then switch to another terminal and launch cap1 script. Unfortunately cap1 gets stuck with the dreaded `select() timeout`.

Comment: Check the CPU load while you run your scripts. The Pi is often simply too slow when you give it a PC's workload.

Answer (score 0):

Try using using grab() and retrieve() instead of read() in multi-camera setups, see [the OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#ae38c2a053d39d6b20c9c649e08ff0146)

I have used this technique to handle 2 cameras in a single thread on a Pi 3, see [this blog post](https://iosoft.blog/position-measurement-low-cost-cameras-opencv/)

Comment: I tried grab() and retrieve(). They only seem to work if I set resolution to 320×240. The cameras are supposed to be 2M pixel, 1600×1200 so it's really frustrating to only be able to use them at a fraction of what they can do. If I only one one camera at a time in a loop, I can grab a few fps @ 1600×1200.

Comment: I was able to get much better resolution than that with 2 cameras. I wonder if the problem is in the way you are handling the data; are you putting it in message queues, and checking for space in the queue before adding more data? The captured data can easily out-pace the image processing, so you need a mechanism for discarding frames if there is a backlog awaiting processing.